# Singular symplectic reduction in infinite dimension

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, singularity-theory, infinite-dimensional-manifolds

In 1991, Sjamaar and Lerman [1] introduced the notion of *stratified symplectic spaces*. Namely, if $M$ is a symplectic manifold and $G$ a Lie group acting properly (but not necessarily freely) on $M$ and there is a moment map $\mu:M\to{\frak g}^*$ for this action, then they show that the symplectic reduction
$$M//G:=\mu^{-1}(0)/G$$
is union a symplectic manifolds that "fit nicely together", in the sense that they form a topological stratification of $M$.

In another 1991 paper [2], which summarizes the results of [1], Sjamaar and Cushman pose the following problem:

> "Try to generalize the results of this paper to any of the various infinite-dimensional situations arising in mathematical physics, e.g. Yang-Mills theory and the Einstein equations."

Has there been some progress towards this goal?

---

[1] *Reyer Sjamaar and Eugene Lerman*, MR 1127479 [**Stratified symplectic spaces and reduction**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2944350), *Ann. of Math. (2)* **134** (1991), no. 2, 375--422.

[2] *Richard Cushman and Reyer Sjamaar*, [**On singular reduction of Hamiltonian spaces**](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~sjamaar/papers/sour.pdf), Progr. Math. **99** (1991), 114-128.

Comment: this means somehow flips in MMP , see paper of Tian with La nave

Comment: http://arxiv.org/abs/1304.5728